# Curl K8s metrics server using start and end time

Tags: kubernetes, curl, prometheus, metrics-server

This is a branch off of my previous post:
[How to get metrics from Kubernetes Metrics-server with a specific window parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76343518/how-to-get-metrics-from-kubernetes-metrics-server-with-a-specific-window-paramet?noredirect=1#comment134629376_76343518)

The answer did help me get results from my query to Prometheus. But Prometheus (correct me if I'm wrong) is unable to query metrics (for my case I need the MIN/MAX/AVG of the API server CPU and memory) by specifying the namespace, pod, and start and end time. With the following command, I am able to get the CPU and memory from all three K8s API server pods, but only with a default window of 5 minutes:

```
kubectl get --raw "/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/openshift-kube-apiserver/pods/" | jq
```

Here is the output:

```
{
  "kind": "PodMetricsList",
  "apiVersion": "metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1",
  "metadata": {},
  "items": [
    {
      "metadata": {
        "name": "kube-apiserver-guard-master-0.ocp9.pd.f5net.com",
        "namespace": "openshift-kube-apiserver",
        "creationTimestamp": "2023-05-30T23:15:10Z",
        "labels": {
          "app": "guard"
        }
      },
      "timestamp": "2023-05-30T23:15:10Z",
      "window": "5m0s",
      "containers": [
        {
          "name": "guard",
          "usage": {
            "cpu": "0",
            "memory": "868Ki"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "metadata": {
        "name": "kube-apiserver-guard-master-1.ocp9.pd.f5net.com",
        "namespace": "openshift-kube-apiserver",
        "creationTimestamp": "2023-05-30T23:15:10Z",
        "labels": {
          "app": "guard"
        }
      },
      "timestamp": "2023-05-30T23:15:10Z",
      "window": "5m0s",
      "containers": [
        {
          "name": "guard",
          "usage": {
            "cpu": "0",
            "memory": "868Ki"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "metadata": {
        "name": "kube-apiserver-guard-master-2.ocp9.pd.f5net.com",
        "namespace": "openshift-kube-apiserver",
        "creationTimestamp": "2023-05-30T23:15:10Z",
        "labels": {
          "app": "guard"
        }
      },
      "timestamp": "2023-05-30T23:15:10Z",
      "window": "5m0s",
      "containers": [
        {
          "name": "guard",
          "usage": {
            "cpu": "0",
            "memory": "864Ki"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "metadata": {
        "name": "kube-apiserver-master-0.ocp9.pd.f5net.com",
        "namespace": "openshift-kube-apiserver",
        "creationTimestamp": "2023-05-30T23:15:10Z",
        "labels": {
          "apiserver": "true",
          "app": "openshift-kube-apiserver",
          "revision": "19"
        }
      },
      "timestamp": "2023-05-30T23:15:10Z",
      "window": "5m0s",
      "containers": [
        {
          "name": "kube-apiserver",
          "usage": {
            "cpu": "404m",
            "memory": "3013592Ki"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "kube-apiserver-cert-regeneration-controller",
          "usage": {
            "cpu": "0",
            "memory": "15188Ki"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "kube-apiserver-cert-syncer",
          "usage": {
            "cpu": "0",
            "memory": "26016Ki"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "kube-apiserver-check-endpoints",
          "usage": {
            "cpu": "2m",
            "memory": "48108Ki"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "kube-apiserver-insecure-readyz",
          "usage": {
            "cpu": "0",
            "memory": "12940Ki"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "metadata": {
        "name": "kube-apiserver-master-1.ocp9.pd.f5net.com",
        "namespace": "openshift-kube-apiserver",
        "creationTimestamp": "2023-05-30T23:15:10Z",
        "labels": {
          "apiserver": "true",
          "app": "openshift-kube-apiserver",
          "revision": "19"
        }
      },
      "timestamp": "2023-05-30T23:15:10Z",
      "window": "5m0s",
      "containers": [
        {
          "name": "kube-apiserver",
          "usage": {
            "cpu": "337m",
            "memory": "3181316Ki"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "kube-apiserver-cert-regeneration-controller",
          "usage": {
            "cpu": "3m",
            "memory": "33596Ki"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "kube-apiserver-cert-syncer",
          "usage": {
            "cpu": "0",
            "memory": "25576Ki"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "kube-apiserver-check-endpoints",
          "usage": {
            "cpu": "5m",
            "memory": "48516Ki"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "kube-apiserver-insecure-readyz",
          "usage": {
            "cpu": "0",
            "memory": "12744Ki"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "metadata": {
        "name": "kube-apiserver-master-2.ocp9.pd.f5net.com",
        "namespace": "openshift-kube-apiserver",
        "creationTimestamp": "2023-05-30T23:15:10Z",
        "labels": {
          "apiserver": "true",
          "app": "openshift-kube-apiserver",
          "revision": "19"
        }
      },
      "timestamp": "2023-05-30T23:15:10Z",
      "window": "5m0s",
      "containers": [
        {
          "name": "kube-apiserver",
          "usage": {
            "cpu": "246m",
            "memory": "2414920Ki"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "kube-apiserver-cert-regeneration-controller",
          "usage": {
            "cpu": "0",
            "memory": "15764Ki"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "kube-apiserver-cert-syncer",
          "usage": {
            "cpu": "1m",
            "memory": "24760Ki"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "kube-apiserver-check-endpoints",
          "usage": {
            "cpu": "2m",
            "memory": "58352Ki"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "kube-apiserver-insecure-readyz",
          "usage": {
            "cpu": "0",
            "memory": "14684Ki"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to be able to get the metrics from the output of this query, but with a specific start and end time (or custom window would work as well). The output values of this command are also aggregated, so I believe they are the sum or maybe average of the values within the default 5 minute window, I need the query to give me all values within the window I give with a specified step, so I can loop through and get the MIN/MAX/AVG of the CPU and memory. I don't think Prometheus has these values, I'm thinking I most likely need to curl the metrics server directly.

Comment: Just found out that I don't think it's possible to query the metrics server with parameters like start, end, step, etc.

Comment: I've been looking into querying Prometheus now with this command:

`curl -s "http://10.192.248.10:30000/api/v1/query_range" --verbose --get --data-urlencode 'query=container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{namespace="openshift-kube-apiserver", pod="kube-apiserver-master-0.ocp9.pd.f5net.com"}' --data-urlencode 'start=2023-05-26T00:00:00Z' --data-urlencode 'end=2023-05-27T00:00:00Z' --data-urlencode 'step=10s' | jq`

Getting a 200 code, but the result is empty. When I change time and the step, I either get an empty result or I exceed the maximum number of datapoints.

Comment: Please avoid posting long formatted blocks in comment (especially if they are significant fir your question). Rather [edit] question itself, and add it there.

Comment: If you plan on finding min/max/avg of your metric, why iterate it manually, and not use `min_over_time`, `max_over_Time` and `avg_over_time`?

Comment: @markalex Is this metric for Prometheus?

Comment: Those are [functions avilable](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#aggregation_over_time) in Prometheus queries, yes. Full query will be `min_over_time(query=container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{namespace="openshift-kube-apiserver", pod="kube-apiserver-master-0.ocp9.pd.f5net.com"} [1d])`. And in this case you could use `api/v1/query` instead of `api/v1/query_range`.